# Detecting 'Leaving' channel event on server-sided Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel, websocket, redis, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel Echo together with Laravel-Echo-Server & Redis to broadcast on several channels. I am trying to perform an action on the server when someone leaves the channel. I understand how to detect a 'leaving' event on the client side but for my purpose it is not safe enough to have it client sided. So basically I am wondering, if and how it is possible to detect events like 'join' and 'leave' on the server side? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe some ajax is needed